# force close when music stops - Android

Tags: java, android

another new problem described below:

When I press home button when music STILL plays, it closes correctly, but when the sound (that is five seconds long) has finished and I press home button, it gives me a force close. I have tried an else-statement; with no luck.

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
    }
}
```

there my variable mp is a MediaPlayer linked to this `mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.mainsound);`

Ideas?

Comment: you're probably accessing a variable that goes out of scope when it stops playing. Can you post a little more code surrounding the playing of the media?

Comment: it would also be great if you could post some error logs. log collector is a good tool for that: http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.xtralogic.android.logcollector/

Comment: It was the setOnCompletion.... that did this force close; how should I be able to do mp.release(); without getting force closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I solved it. I had a setOnCompletionListener inside my onCreate which lead to I couldn't access my mp, when it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some code elsewhere that nulls out mp when it finishes playing?

Comment: Yes, there my exit-button is located to exit the application.